# SQLAlchemy Max value on column with Null value.

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a list of value. I am trying to find the max of each ID. Where Null is max of all value.

```
ID   DATE     

1     '2013-01-26'
1     NULL
1     '2013-03-03'      
2     '2013-02-23'      
2     '2013-04-12'      
2     '2013-05-02'
```

I want to get this

```
ID   DATE     

1     NULL    
2     '2013-05-02'
```

I know how to do it in mysql. By doing this

```
select ID, max(IFNULL(DATE,'3000-01-01'))
from test
group by ID
```

I want to find the sqlalchemy version of this.

This does assume Null to be the min.

```
db_session.query(test, func.max(test.DATE)).group_by(test.ID).all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```
from datetime import date


# your query
res = session.query(
    Test,
    func.max(func.ifnull(Test.date, date(3000, 1, 1)))
).group_by(Test.id).all()
```

**Note**: you may use also `COALESCE` for this. `COALESCE` is part of standard sql, and it is supported by wider amount of databases.
Example of query with `COALESCE`:

```
res = session.query(
    Test,
    func.max(func.coalesce(Test.date, date(3000, 1, 1)))
).group_by(Test.id).all()
```